# SQL multiple data count from multiple tables with union all

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My existing SQL looks like the below, it will generate only the `total_pending_req` count.

```
SELECT count(table1.employee_code) as total_requests, table1.employee_code as emp_code
FROM table1
WHERE employee_status = 'PENDING'
GROUP BY emp_code

UNION ALL

SELECT count(table2.employee_code) as total_requests, table2.employee_code as emp_code
FROM table2
WHERE employee_status = 'PENDING'
GROUP BY emp_code

UNION ALL

SELECT count(table3.employee_code) as total_requests, table3.employee_code as emp_code
FROM table3
WHERE employee_status = 'PENDING'
GROUP BY emp_code
```

This will return the result below,

[image]

I want to get the **request count** as `total_pending_req`, `total_rejected_req` and `total_completed_req` considering 3 different tables. All tables have the same status codes, `PENDING`, `COMPLETED` and `REJECTED`. The final result should be like this,

[image]

I would like to have an idea, of how to extract data more efficiently, since I have to use `UNION ALL`. May I know if there is any better approach to extract data more efficiently? I would appreciate your help on this.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: @RF1991 Sorry I am using Postgresql. I updated the tagging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `CASE` and `Union All` as follows

```
select 
table1.employee_code as emp_code,
case employee_status = 'PENDING' then count(table1.employee_code)  else 0 end as PENDING,
case employee_status = 'COMPLETED' then count(table1.employee_code)  else 0 end as COMPLETED,
case employee_status = 'REJECTED' then count(table1.employee_code)  else 0 end as REJECTED   
from FROM table1
GROUP BY emp_code
UNION ALL
select 
table2.employee_code as emp_code,
case employee_status = 'PENDING' then count(table2.employee_code)  else 0 end as PENDING,
case employee_status = 'COMPLETED' then count(table2.employee_code)  else 0 end as COMPLETED,
case employee_status = 'REJECTED' then count(table2.employee_code)  else 0 end as REJECTED   
from FROM table2
GROUP BY emp_code
UNION ALL
select 
table3.employee_code as emp_code,
case employee_status = 'PENDING' then count(table3.employee_code)  else 0 end as PENDING,
case employee_status = 'COMPLETED' then count(table3.employee_code)  else 0 end as COMPLETED,
case employee_status = 'REJECTED' then count(table3.employee_code)  else 0 end as REJECTED   
from FROM table3
GROUP BY emp_code
```

Or using `SUM` and `Case`

```
SELECT 
table1.employee_code as emp_code,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'PENDING' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as PENDING,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'COMPLETED' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as COMPLETED,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'REJECTED' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as REJECTED
from FROM table1
GROUP BY emp_code
UNION ALL
SELECT 
table2.employee_code as emp_code,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'PENDING' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as PENDING,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'COMPLETED' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as COMPLETED,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'REJECTED' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as REJECTED
from FROM table2
GROUP BY emp_code
UNION ALL
SELECT 
table3.employee_code as emp_code,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'PENDING' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as PENDING,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'COMPLETED' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as COMPLETED,
SUM(CASE employee_status = 'REJECTED' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as REJECTED
from FROM table3
GROUP BY emp_code
```

Comment: The bulk of project delivery cost is maintenance cost. Find the right abstraction. Don't. Repeat. Yourself. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: appreciate your Notice @J_H. but the desired result is only available with the query

Comment: Eventhough there is an issue with performance and maintenance, this query is the one I expected. I also agree with @J_H but with the current table structure, my lead expects just a query.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your rows appear in the
several table{1,2,3} relations is just
an annoying distraction.
Let's make it a single relation, already.
We could create a table or a view.

```
CREATE VIEW combined AS
(SELECT * FROM table1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM table2
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT * FROM table3
 UNION ALL
)
```

Good!

With that out of the way, it becomes a trivial GROUP BY.

```
SELECT    employee_code, employee_status, COUNT(*)
FROM      combined
GROUP BY  employee_code, employee_status
```

You can phrase it as a
[CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)
if you're averse to DDL.
Or create a VIEW that does the UNION ALL heavy lifting.
Or a MATERIALIZED VIEW, whatever.

---

The output format is three emps × three statuses,
or nine rows.

If you really need three rows, feel free to SELECT
from that relation to re-format it.

Comment: This looks great, but the problem is, this way it will create another table. Currently, all three tables contain data that are being updated frequently. I am just creating a proc using the above SQL query to create an API to get the result as mentioned above. May I know is there any alternative way to solve this?

Comment: Your remark describes an aversion to DDL, since DROP / INSERT certainly can be time consuming, that's an understandable concern. I encourage you to pay careful attention to the CTE / VIEW / MATERIALIZED VIEW options I offered. Having rows scattered among diverse tables is distracting you from focusing on a unified relation that has all the data you need for an effective GROUP BY.

Comment: I tried to explain this to my senior level. But they expect just a query. Also, I researched the performance gap between stored proc and view, As I can see, there is no huge gap between them. Do you see any other drawbacks to not using stored proc?

Comment: @RYJ It does not create another table, just view description. In fact you can do it inside single view (inside procedure) too - `select what_you_want from (select ... union alll ... etcetc)` without creating intermediate view.

Comment: Where did "stored procedure" even begin to become relevant to this question? I don't see it explicitly mentioned, nor implied. Elapsed time to complete a query seemed relevant, which is why I mentioned that MATERIALIZED VIEW might be attractive if there's no indexes to support performant VIEW queries. Note that a CTE clause is essentially identical to a VIEW -- it creates a conveniently formatted relation that we can pull relevant rows from.

Comment: @Arvo My bad, I thought it as a Table, not View, that's why I confused. Just got the point.

Comment: @J_H Actually, I am going to create a stored proc using this query. Then the back-end app (Spring Boot) will call this proc to retrieve data. My bad, I confused, I thought it was a table, not a view, the query you mentioned above. I believe I need to refer more about MATERIALIZED VIEW, as you mentioned it would be the exact solution for this. I appreciate your help comments to understand the basics.